# select a value from different tables depending on a condition

Tags: mysql

I am working on an inventory system. We have stored transactions in a transactions table which stores `(challanid, challandate, toid, fromid, toenittyid)`. `Toentity` can be a `branch`, `distributor`, `dealer` or `stockist` which are stored in different tables. I need to build a query for transactions over a period of time which shows all transactions. For this I need to show `entityname` which needs to be withdrawn by toid from respecitve `dealer/distributor` or `stockist` tables depending on `toenitytid`.

For example, if `toentityid` is 2, we need to get `branchname` from `branch` table, if `toentityid` is 3 we need to get `stockistname` from `stockist` table by `toid` and so on. I tried switch case, but that does not work to change the table name. I need help to complete this query. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Didn't you try anything? You can follow this page instruction to post a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I checked. I have tried but I found that join can not be created from a condition.

Comment: can you post your query along with some sample input and if possible expected output ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use something approximately like this; I think you will see how.

```
CREATE VIEW TransactionEntity 
AS
SELECT 2 AS EntityType, Branch.* FROM Branch
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS EntityType, Stockist.* FROM Stockist
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS EntityType, ...
```

The tables may have different column names from each other, in which case you shouldn't use "*".  The column names of the view are the column names assigned in the first SELECT statement, but those can be changed from actual column names.

A different method, more complicated, more efficient (I think), is this:

```
SELECT 
      tr.*
    , COALESCE(br.branchname, st.stockistname, - other columns - )
      AS entityname
FROM
transactions     tr
LEFT OUTER JOIN
branch           br
ON
( tr.toentity = 2 AND tr.toid = br.branchid )
LEFT OUTER JOIN
stockist         st
ON
( tr.toentity = 3 AND tr.toid = st.stockistid ) -- corrected mistake of ':' should be '.'
LEFT OUTER JOIN
- other tables that are needed -
```

The result of COALESCE is the first of its terms that is not NULL.  So, if the transaction is to a branch, then branchname produces the value.  If the transaction is to a stockist, then branchname is NULL but stockistname produces the value.  And so on, for the other tables that may hold the data that you need.

(Updated - typing mistake in the code example, corrected, see the comment)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I didn't fully get the question complete. I'd suggest using dynamic sql with dictionary of table names and a query to evaluate a specific condition. You can do that with selecting count of records that satisfy the condition needed to select from the table you want. But since you've tagged the question in mysql I think you can benefit from this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190776/how-to-have-dynamic-sql-in-mysql-stored-procedure)